# How to fetch all the data from list and store in my JavaScript array in SP2013 designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, spservices

When I open my list form that time I want to fetch all the data from the contact list and store in my javascript array.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve items to array using JSOM , you should use `loadQuery` instead of `load`.

```
function Getallitems() { 

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
    var List = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('your list name');
    var cquery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();

    var query = List.getItems(cquery);
    var allitems = ctx.loadQuery(query);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) { alert("Succeed");}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

`allitems` is now working as array.

Comment: Thank you for reply where can i write this code? i am using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: you are welcome, but should you tell me what you are doing using Designer to can help you how to use it, where it's client side code that you can use it at control event like onclick event at button

Comment: I want to bind the contract list record  to my drop down when page load also i want to bind only those record which related to  select the customer. customer type is external data.

Comment: I want to implement logic like this http://prnt.sc/ccxmlg

Comment: Should we continue to this room because your question needs more details http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44476/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-admin